# Is there a easy-used two-way encryption method for string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a easy-used two-way encryption method for string in ruby?

Answer (score 1):

This article discusses someone who wrapped [RSA encryption and decryption in Ruby](http://nunojob.wordpress.com/2008/12/08/rsa-encrypt-decrypt-in-ruby/). As I do not speak the language I cannot attest to its usefulness, but I couldn't let the Base64 answer go unchallenged.

Public-key cryptography of any kind is going to be the best solution, depending on what you're after. The user can be completely unaware of its existence if you do it right.

Looks like the `openssl` module (gem?) is a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/index.html

Comment: Upon re-reading your question it seems like I misunderstood...leaving my answer just in case this really is what you were looking for.

Comment: base64 is not encryption is encoding.

Comment: I would like to reiterate, that base64 is NOT encryption and it is NOT safe to send/store data this way that you don't want read. 

This answer should probably be deleted.